# Maximum of a Line Integral of the Vector Field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem: Let $S$ be the graph of $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2/2}$.
Let $F=<x+y,xy,sin(e^x)>$ be a vector field. To which level curve does the line integral of the vector field attains maximum?

How do I approach this? I'm at a loss.